# Permutohedron: Wikipedia vs. Günter Matthias Ziegler

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra, polytopes

The [Wikipedia site on permutohedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron#Examples) displays a drawing of a 3-permutohedron in which vertices $\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ are connected by an edge:

[image: drawing]

However, Günter Matthias Ziegler in "[Lectures on Polytopes](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-8431-1)", ISBN 978-1-4613-8431-1, Example 0.10, p. 17, displays a drawing of a permutohedron $\Pi_2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ with a labeling of the vertices in which the two aformentioned vertices are not connected by an edge:
[image: Ziegler's $\Pi_2$]
Is Ziegler just wrong there or am I misinterpreting his drawing?

Comment: The hexagon in Ziegler's book is arranged like this: $$ \begin{array}{ccccc} & & 132 \\  123 & & & & 312 \\ \\ 213 & & & & 321 \\ & & 231 \end{array} $$

Comment: Sorry --- I should have written $\mathbb R^3$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy that array come out looking very nice!

Comment: @snulty : Thanks to MathJax. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two sources are using different notation.

Ziegler's vertex $(312)$ is a permutation that maps $x_3$ to $1$, $x_1$ to $2$, and $x_2$ to $3$, corresponding to the point $(2,3,1)$ in space. It is adjacent to $(132)$ and $(321)$ (Ziegler notation) which are points $(1,3,2)$ and $(3,2,1)$, all of which is consistent with the Wikipedia picture.